# What is the preferred way of writing small numbers in academic writing?

Tags: formatting, scientific-publishing

I need to represent small numbers in multiple tables. I am wondering which is the preferred way:
1.235e-3, or 1.235x10^-3?

The issue is that the latter requires more width than the former. Hence, most of the tables may extend the page width.

Comment: All the examples I see are 1.235x10-3 and including the common measures, so if something is usually reported in microliters, they don't give the values in milliliters, so it's important to know what the standard is for the given thing they are reporting on. Of course, I mostly see medical, but when I worked in academia (20 years ago) they did the same. I don't know if this is true in the field you are working in, so I'm just giving it as a comment.

Comment: @DWKraus: Thanks :)

Comment: First, use SI units only. Don't change to other units. Also, in tables, the column heading can give the key to understanding the numbers in the table. If every number in a column is a thousandth (x10^-3), then there's no reason to put that in every cell. A table column heading can say "Population in millions" and the table cells have simple numbers like "1.3" -- for a population of 1,300,000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, consult your style guide. Otherwise, yes, you can use "e format".

According to the NIST's [Guide for the Use of the International System of Units (SI)](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/sp811.pdf):

> The factors given in Secs. B.8 and B.9 are written as a number equal to or greater than 1 and less than 10, with 6 or fewer decimal places. The number is followed by the letter E, which stands for exponent, a plus (+) or minus (–) sign, and two digits that indicate the power of 10 by which the number is multiplied.
>
> Examples:
>
> - 3.523 907 E−02 means 3.523 907 × 10−2 = 0.035 239 07
> - 3.386 389 E+03 means 3.386 389 × 103 = 3386.389

(Note: as the tables in the sections referenced are conversation tables, it's possible to have a lot of precision. This is not often the case with measurements.)

They also point out that it's often appropriate to use a different SI prefix (e.g. nm instead of m).

A similar format is allowed by the publisher [AGU](https://www.agu.org/Publish-with-AGU/Publish/Author-Resources/Grammar-Style-Guide), for example.